# Why is my Apache2 webserver on my Ubuntu server 22.04.1 not loading some of the images

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

So I have uploaded and done all the steps to host my website on my ubuntu server using apache2 I doubled check the files and code but some of the images on the website are not loading.

This is the log:
[image]

This is what I see from the network console:

[image]

These are the image files:

These are the files on the server:

![The field are in the server guaranteed as shown in the Console][4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of Apache instances are case sensitive by default. Your website is asking for `copper_ore.webp`, `iron_ore.webp`, and `gold_ore.webp`. However these files are stored as `Copper_ore.webp`, `Iron_ore.webp`, and `Gold_ore.webp` on the server. The simplest solution would be to change the case of the files to all be lower-case, and you'll probably want to do this for `Silver_ore.webp` as well.

Comment: I changed it to them and re uploaded and it still did not work

Comment: If you haven't done so already, you will want to disable the cache in the browser while the Developer Tools are open. This will ensure that resources are grabbed from the server with every request rather than using the browser's local cache, which will remember the 404s from before. If the images continue to fail, you will want to check the Apache log (`/var/log/apache2/{site}-error.log`) and/or the HTML source to ensure the path is correct.

Comment: IT seems to not be updating al all even with cache disabled and I also replaced the old folder

Comment: It's good now I did some stuff and it worked